# Find $\frac{d}{dy}\int^y_1 \frac{1}{1+x+x^2} dx$

Tags: calculus

How do you find

$$\frac{d}{dy}\int^y_1 \frac{1}{1+x+x^2} dx$$

I actually have a problem with the integral.

What happens after that is I will do

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dy}\int^y_1 f'(x) dx
&= \frac{d}{dy}\begin{vmatrix}f(x)\end{vmatrix}^{x=y}_{x=1}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Fundamental theorem of calculus. First part: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus

Comment: Either I'm being extremely naive, or it's much harder than it looks. Is this not just a question about the fundamental theorem of calculus? Won't the 'x' act as a "dummy variable" and the result will be the integrand with 'y' replacing all the 'x's?

Comment: Never mind, Julien beat me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part
What I suspect you may be presently encountering in your class or text is:

- [**The First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)

You're certainly encountering an opportunity to use it here! From the linked Wikipedia article,

> Let f be a continuous real-valued function defined on a closed interval [a, b]. Let $F$ be the function defined, for all $x \in [a, b],$ by
>
> $$F(x) = \int_a^x\!f(t)\, dt.$$
>
> Then, F is continuous on $[a, b]$, differentiable on the open interval $(a, b)$, and
>
> $$F'(x) = f(x)\; \text{ for all}\; x \in (a, b).$$

In your problem, the only difference is you're given the actual function of interest, and the variables used are different. So adjusting for the difference between the variables used in the theorem and the variables used in your problem:

Put $\displaystyle F'(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+ x + x^2}.$ Then $\,\int_1^y\!\dfrac{1}{1+ x + x^2}\, dx = F(y) - F(1),$

so $\;\frac d{dy}(F(y) - F(1)) = \frac d{dy}(F(y)) = f(y) = \dfrac{1}{1 + y + y^2}$

No actual "brute force* integrating then differentiating needed!

Comment: Hello @amWhy, I would like to ask 1 last question regarding this - is it because $F(1)$ will result in a constant, hence $F'(1) = 0$ ?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Does this help? ;-)

Comment: Yes, it does! Thank you, I finally understood it.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $\,F(x)\,$ is such that

$$F'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x+x^2}\,\Longrightarrow \int\limits_1^y\frac{dx}{1+x+x^2}=F(y)-F(1)\Longrightarrow$$

$$\frac{d}{dy}\left(\int\limits_1^y\frac{dx}{1+x+x^2}\right)=\frac{d}{dy}\left(F(y)-F(1)\right)=F'(y)=\frac{1}{1+y+y^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

You did it right so far. Just keep going and differentiate. The answer will be
$$
\frac{1}{1+y+y^2}.
$$
Note that you don't have to do it the way you did. One of the fundamental theorems of calculus is that if there is a function defined in terms of an integral, $f(y) = \int_1^y g(x) \, dx$, then $f'(y) = g(y)$ which is much more straight forward. Note that the constant lower bound can be anything in the domain of $g$.

Answer (score 1):

[Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondFundamentalTheoremofCalculus.html).

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d}{dy}\int^y_1 dx\: \frac{1}{1+x+x^2} = \frac{1}{1+y+y^2}$$